# Java - map 2 keys of different types to the same value (any type). How can I go about it?

Tags: java, dictionary, key

OK here's the scenario. I have **static** pairs of keys that **always go together**. One key is the index (aka `int`) and one key is the description (aka `string` or `enum`). I know all these keys **in advance** so the only thing that's really changing are the values, new keys are never added.

The values however can be any type: string, int, long. Some values are not singular and are made of more than one value. I do know however, in advance, to which type of value each key pair will point.

The values will most likely always be set using the index. However, I want to be able to access the values **quickly** (no loops please, and hopefully no casting either) by **either** the index(int) or the description (string/enum). Also, when accessing the values via the index I should also have access to the description

This might make things clearer:

```
1/Name ----> "danny"        //1 and Name are known in advance and always go together. also, they always point to a string
2/Age  ----> 24             //2 and Age are known in advance and always go together. also, they always point to an int
3/Time ----> 352343463463L  //3 and Time are known in advance and always go together. also, they always point to a long
4/Occupation    ---> [description] "magician"
                ---> [type] "entertainer"
                ---> [years] 3              //4 and Status are known in advance and always go together. also they will always point to 2 strings and and an int (or an object contraining 2 strings and an int...)
```

Functionality needed:

```
set(1, "Jasmine");
get(1);             //returns "Jasmine"
get(Name);          //return "Jasmine"  (name can be either string or enum I suppose)
getDescription(1);  // returns Name (again, name could be either string or enum). this function could possibly be merged with get(1) to have it return both description and value in the first place.

set(2, 32);
get(2);             //returns 32
get(Age);            //returns 32
```

Comment: Please clarify what on earth you mean by 'same different'.

Comment: You know, what you're describing is basically a class with properties...

Comment: The 2 keys will always point to the same value. That value however can be of any type. Thus the keys point to the same different type value. It's a topic so I tried making it short as possible :)

Comment: It's impossible to create a method `get(int)` that will return a different compile-time type depending  on the value of the int.  So forget about not having to cast for the lookup by index.

Answer (score 2):

create

```
class Entry {
  int index;
  String description;
  Object value;
}
```

declare 2 HashMaps:

```
HashMap<Integer, Entry> idxValue=new HashMap<Integer, Entry>();
HashMap<String, Entry> descrValue=new HashMap<String, Entry>();
```

define methods to store and retrieve entries and values which work with both tables.

Comment: how can he use this to set the value using index only and then get it back using description?

Comment: @herman `idxValue.get(index).setValue((Object) othervalue)`, `descrValue.get(description)` will now point to the new changed object with `othervalue` in it. +1 Hashmap is the way to go

Comment: @herman yes this is problematic. When a value is stored, both index and description should be provided. So the examples in the question are inconsistent.

Comment: @reverse_engineer Yes, if Entry is mutable, but I'm not sure that's a good idea.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov See my answer: it doesn't require both index and description when storing the value.  According to the question, the mapping between index and description is static.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [TypedMap](http://blog.pdark.de/2010/05/28/type-safe-object-map/) for this. In a nutshell, it gives you a type-safe map which can store any kind of object as value under a key:

```
TypedMap map = new TypedMap();

String expected = "Hallo";
map.set( KEY1, expected );
String value = map.get( KEY1 ); // Look Ma, no cast!
assertEquals( expected, value );

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String> ();
map.set( KEY2, list );
List<String> valueList = map.get( KEY2 ); // Even with generics
assertEquals( list, valueList );
```

To give you fast access to the typed keys, I suggest to use an enum:

```
enum Key {
    Name(1) { @Override public TypedMapKey<String> getKey() { return NAME_KEY; },
    ...;

    private static Key[] byIndex = new Key[MAX_INDEX+1];
    static {
        for( Key key : values() ) { byIndex[key.index] = key; }
    }

    public static byIndex(int index) {
        return byIndex[index]; // I suggest non-null checks here if you have gaps
    }

    private Key(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public TypedMapKey<?> getKey() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "Please override"; ) }
}
```

Comment: I assume the magic here is in the `KEY1` (or `KEY2`) declaration which isn't shown, i.e. the map key is the carrier of type information.

Comment: I looked at your `TypedMap`, but it seems flawed: the casting is happening in the `TypedMap` itself, and it's still possible to put objects of the wrong type in the map.

Comment: @herman: That's because it also implements the `Map` interface. If you want to be really save, have `put( String key, Object value )` throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. With this, casting is always safe because you can't put the wrong object into the map anymore. Alternatively, you can drop the `Map` interface but then, it's no longer a drop-in replacement for a Java map.

Comment: @BorisB.: Yes. The whole code is behind the link plus explanations.

Comment: You have different options for getting around the cast if you can use custom keys, but he wants to use a simple index (`Integer`) and an `enum` (or `String`) as keys.

Comment: @AaronDigulla enum inheritance is not possible and if he has to use `TypedMapKey<?>` he'll still need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED
Here's my definitive answer:

You have a static relationship between an index, a description and the type of value that is associated with it.  So let's capture this in a class:

```
public class Key<VALUETYPE> {
    private final Integer          index;
    private final String           description;
    private final Class<VALUETYPE> valueType;

    public Key(final Integer index, final String description, final Class<VALUETYPE> valueType) {
        super();
        this.index = index;
        this.description = description;
        this.valueType = valueType;
    }

    public Integer getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Class<VALUETYPE> getValueType() {
        return valueType;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return index.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) { return true; }
        if (obj == null) { return false; }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) { return false; }
        Key<?> other = (Key<?>) obj;
        return index.equals(other.index);
    }
}
```

I've assumed the indexes to be unique identifiers of the key, so have based `hashCode` and `equals` on it.

Now you write an accessor class that covers your use cases:

```
public class MapAccessor {
    private final Map<Integer, Key<?>> keyMap;
    private final Map<Key<?>, Object>  valueMap;

    public MapAccessor(final Map<Integer, Key<?>> keysByIndex, final Map<Key<?>, Object> valueMap) {
        this.keyMap = keysByIndex;
        this.valueMap = valueMap;
    }

    public void put(final Integer index, final Object value) {
        Key<?> key = keyMap.get(index);
        if (key.getValueType().isInstance(value) || value == null) {
            valueMap.put(key, value);
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong type of value for index " + index + ", expected: " + key.getValueType()
                    + ", actual: " + value.getClass());
        }
    }

    public <VALUETYPE> VALUETYPE get(final Key<VALUETYPE> key) {
        return key.getValueType().cast(valueMap.get(key));
    }

    public Object get(final Integer index) {
        Key<?> key = getKey(index);
        return key == null ? null : get(key);
    }

    public Key<?> getKey(final Integer index) {
        return keyMap.get(index);
    }

    public String getDescription(final Integer index) {
        Key<?> key = getKey(index);
        return key == null ? null : key.getDescription();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could put this in a subclass of `HashMap<Key<?>, Object>` instead of delegating to it.

Let's demonstrate how to use the above.  Note that a cast is unavoidable for lookup by index.

```
public class ExampleUsage {
    private static final Key<String>   NAME  = new Key<>(1, "Name", String.class);
    private static final Key<Integer>  AGE   = new Key<>(2, "Age", Integer.class);

    private static final Map<Integer, Key<?>> keysByIndex = buildKeysByIndex(NAME, AGE);

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        Map<Key<?>, Object> valueMap = new HashMap<>();

        MapAccessor accessor = new MapAccessor(keysByIndex, valueMap);

        accessor.put(1, "Jasmine");
        String nameByIndex = (String) accessor.get(1); // returns "Jasmine", cast can't be avoided
        String nameByKey = accessor.get(NAME); // returns "Jasmine", no cast necessary
        Key<?> nameKeyByIndex = accessor.getKey(1); // returns NAME
        String nameDescriptionByIndex = accessor.getDescription(1); // returns "Name"

        accessor.put(2, 32);
        Integer ageByIndex = (Integer) accessor.get(2); // returns 32, cast can't be avoided
        Integer ageByKey = accessor.get(AGE); // returns 32, no cast necessary
        Key<?> ageKeyByIndex = accessor.getKey(2); // returns AGE
        String ageDescriptionByIndex = accessor.getDescription(2); // returns "Age"
    }

    private static Map<Integer, Key<?>> buildKeysByIndex(final Key<?>... keys) {
        Map<Integer, Key<?>> keyMap = new HashMap<Integer, Key<?>>();
        for (Key<?> key : keys) {
            keyMap.put(key.getIndex(), key);
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(keyMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the depth of your solution. I am still trying to wrap my head around this as it involves some java procedures I am unfamiliar with and now reading about (I only started using about a week ago). Before I fully get to the bottom of this, I just need to ask one thing in advance: You provided 4 getters, one explicitly uses a cast. Is there any casting done when using any of the 3 other getters or will they run as fast as any simple map getter?

Comment: The getter using a `Key` (which is used by the 2 other getters in `MapAccessor`) does a dynamic cast to be able to fail fast in case the value map would have been updated outside the accessor using a wrongly typed value.  This is not a big performance impact, but you could replace it by a static (compile-time) cast to (VALUETYPE) which is removed after compilation (due to erasure), and ignore the safety warning, if you like.  As long as only the `MapAccessor` class is used to manipulate the map, the values will be of the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple class to hold the data and make things like `Name`, `Age`, etc. bean-like properties with a backing field:

```
private int age; 

public getAge() { return age; } 

public setAge(int value) { age = value; }
```

Make a custom annotation called `@FieldInfo` which contains a field ordinal and a field description:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)    
public @interface FieldInfo {
    int ordinal();
    String description();
}
```

Decorate the data class with your annotation:

```
@FieldInfo(ord=1, description="Age")
private int age; 

public getAge() { return age; } 

public setAge(int value) { age = value; }
```

Make  a base class for your data class which contains universal `get()` and `set()` methods which can get/set values using the field ordinal and a getDescription() method which returns the field description given the ordinal. Use `this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` to get `Fields[]` using reflection, and then use `Field.getAnnotation(FieldInfo.class)` to get the annotation for each field.

Since data class properties don't change at runtime you can build two static lookups `<int, Field>` and `<int, String>` for each data class type in a static constructor to speed things up if you are frequently using ordinals to access fields. Using this approach you can further describe fields by extending the annotation and your data class is still a simple class with traditional getters/setters.